# Prepend each element to its respective adjacent element

Tags: jquery

I have a list of articles, each with a `.cat-title` and a `.other`. I'm trying to prepend each `.cat-title` to its respective `.other`. Here's what I've tried but I'm having a difficult time understanding the `.each` function.

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {

jQuery('.cat-title').each(function() {
  jQuery(this).prependTo(.other);
}

});
```

Markup:

```
<div>

  <span class="cat-title>Test</span>
  <a class="other" href="/">Link</a>

  <span class="cat-title>Test</span>
  <a class="other" href="/">Link</a>

  <span class="cat-title>Test</span>
  <a class="other" href="/">Link</a>

  </div>

</div>
```

Desired result:

```
<div>

  <a class="other" href="/">Link
    <span class="cat-title>Test</span>
  </a>

  <a class="other" href="/">Link
    <span class="cat-title>Test</span>
  </a>

  <a class="other" href="/">Link
    <span class="cat-title>Test</span>
  </a>

</div>
```

Comment: just `jQuery('.cat-title').prependTo('.other a');` it enough

Comment: @John That makes every `.cat-title` prepend to every `.other a` which is not what I want.

Comment: ah okey i see could you post your html markup ?

Comment: @John I added a simplified version of the mockup. I want each `.cat-title` inside `.other a`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
jQuery('.cat-title').each(function(){
  // caching the variable:
  let el = jQuery(this);

  // prepending the current element of the
  // collection to the element found via
  // the selector passed to the method,
  // which traverses from the current element
  // to its next <a> element sibling, returning 
  // that element to the method:
  el.prependTo(el.next('a'));
});
```

Or:

```
// finds the <a> elements first, and then
// uses the anonymous function of the 
// prepend() method:
jQuery('a').prepend(function(){
  // within the method's function 'this'
  // refers to the <a> element over which
  // the method iterates.

  // here we find the previous sibling,
  // the <a> element, if it matches
  // the selector, returning that element
  // to the method:
    return jQuery(this).prev('.cat-title');
});
```

References:

- [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/).
- [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).
- [`prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/).
- [`prev`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/).

Comment: Thanks, David. I tried this and it wasn't working and I realized that I wrote the markup down wrong. I made a small revision. Can you please take a look and let me know what changes I'd have to make to your code?

Comment: Edited the answer.

Comment: I'm glad to have been of help!

Comment: Hey David, I have the script in the footer of my site and everything is working fine on desktop, but on mobile (iPhone 6s) the jQuery code doesn't seem to be registering. I checked the DOM through Firebug Lite for Iphone and it looks like the `span` element doesn't get moved into the `a` element at all. I know this is a bit out of the original question, but I was wondering if you had any thoughts at all as to why this would happen. Btw, I've tried putting the script in the head as well but still no dice.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the selector inside the each function:

$.each(jQuery('.cat-title'), function( index, value ) {
    $(value).prependTo('.other a');
  });